# How to use cscope to search for multiple C symbols at once

Tags: c, cscope

Is it possible to have **Cscope** return search results for multiple C symbols at once ?

I have a huge project with a bunch of `header(.h)` and `.c` files and I want to find all instances of `foo()` and `bar()`( maybe more ) in my project at once.

Currently, when I do a `cscope -d`, I am able to search for one C symbol at a time, but how can i do the following :

`Find this C symbol: foo || bar`.  ( This doesn't work )

So, in short I want the Cscope search to be able to work as a **logical OR**. How can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The help message from Cscope (15.7a) says in part:

> Press the RETURN key repeatedly to move to the desired input field, type the
> pattern to search for, and then press the RETURN key.  For the first 4 and
> last 2 input fields, the pattern can be a regcomp(3) regular expression.
> If the search is successful, you can use these single-character commands:

and the input fields referred to are these:

> ```
> Find this C symbol:
> Find this global definition:
> Find functions called by this function:
> Find functions calling this function:
> Find this text string:
> Change this text string:
> Find this egrep pattern:
> Find this file:
> Find files #including this file:
> ```

The regex matching doesn't apply to the two text string operations or the `egrep` pattern.  However, the help doesn't explicitly say that it uses extended regular expressions, though studying the source code shows that it does.

From the Cscope project at SourceForge, I have the source for [Cscope 15.8b](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cscope/files/cscope/) from April 2015.  In the directory `cscope-15.8b/src` is the file `find.c`.  In `find.c`, at line 712ff, there is the code:

```
 712     /* see if the pattern is a regular expression */
 713     if (strpbrk(pattern, "^.[{*+$") != NULL) {
 714         isregexp = YES;
 715     } else {
```

If it spots one of the regex metacharacters listed, it uses extended regular expression mode.  The trouble is, that list of characters does not include either `|` or `(`, both of which are metacharacters too.

When the code is changed to:

```
 712     /* see if the pattern is a regular expression */
 713     if (strpbrk(pattern, "^.[{*+$|(") != NULL) {
 714         isregexp = YES;
 715     } else {
```

and recompiled, then I can search for `foo|bar` successfully.  Without the change, `cscope` reports that `foo|bar` is not a valid C symbol — which is correct but not helpful.

A similar change may be beneficial if you can find the source code.

---

When I use Cscope 15.7a, even including one of the characters listed doesn't seem to turn on extended regular expressions, but it does allow simple (basic) regular expressions to work.  For example, `err_(remark|error)$` includes the `$`, but doesn't match anything.  Using `err.*` does work; using `err_[er][er][mo][ar]r.*` doesn't work.  So, it seems that regex-support is mostly new in Cscope 15.8 or thereabouts.

---

See also Cscope [Issue 294](https://sourceforge.net/p/cscope/bugs/294/) at SourceForge.  It cross-references this question.

Comment: This was really helpful. I thought I had already upvoted and accepted this. Really appreciate the effort into this answer. Apologies for the delay !

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use the find this egrep pattern search field (TAB to access).

e.g.:

Find this egrep pattern: (foo|bar)

Comment: While this works, it will also report on instances of `buffoon` and `hyperbarics` in the code.

Comment: True. A slightly improved pattern would yield a more accurate response. Something like: (foo\\(|bar\\() would probably suffice for the OP's needs.